# ROR adding indexes properly in migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm new to rails, and I'm trying to create an events based app.

When the database is eventually filled with recorded events, I'd like to be able to perform a general search and list them based on either their name, address, or start date. (I will eventually be geocoding the results and showing multiple events on a google map)

For a separate purpose on a user profile page I'll also need to be able to search them based on the user_id, and list them in reverse order of their created_at timestamp.

I'm not sure how to add the indexes properly in the migration file. This is my current migration file:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date
      t.references :group, index: true
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.integer :privacy
      t.text :content

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :events, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

I tried to do this:

```
add_index :events, [:user_id, :created_at, :address, :start_time]
```

but received this error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_events_on_user_id_and_created_at_and_address_and_start_time' on table 'events' is too long; the limit is 62 characters/Users/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.0.beta4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:884:in `add_index_options'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message details, the default name used by rails for creating the index is too long. You can get around this error by implicitly specifying the name as follows:

```
add_index :events, [:user_id, :created_at, :address, :start_time], name: 'index_name'
```

Come up with a suitable value for `index_name`.